# Comparar fecha DATE ignorando HHMMSS - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date

tengo la siguiente duda, como puedo ignorar las horas, minutos, y segundos en una fecha(DATE) en una consulta en base de datos.
tengo lo siguiente:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLA
WHERE CAMPO = to_date('25042019','DDMMYYYY');
```

pero al consultarlo no me trae nada, habiendo registros con esa informacion.
revisando me di cuenta que el campo tiene el siguiente valor.

[image: s]

Entonces cuando la consulto, asumo que falta darle ese valor igual, no se realmente si sera una configuracion en el IDE, USO ORACLE SQL DEVELOPER.

Cuando consulto otra fecha que tiene valor 00:00:00 no me genera ningun problema y me muestra correctamente la informacion.

La idea es ignorar las horas, minutos y segundos, y solo buscarlo por la fecha en formato DDMMYYYY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer uso de la función `TRUNC` de Oracle así:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLA
WHERE TRUNC(CAMPO) = TO_DATE('25042019','DDMMYYYY')
```

Esta función, en el caso de fechas, recibe dos parámetros, el primero de ellos es la fecha que quieres truncar y el segundo la unidad de medida (este parámetro es opcional). En el ejemplo que te di arriba, estoy omitiendo la unidad de medida, por lo que la función `TRUNC` toma la unidad por defecto, que es día. Así, se omitirán las horas, minutos y segundos y sólo quedará lo correspondiente a año, mes y día.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvio tu respuesta, y de paso se entendio perfecto tu explicacion